# Gradle application plugin: how to change the path in the archive

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to use the Gradle 'application' plugin to create an archive of my application with all its dependencies. However, the zip (or tar) file created contains a root folder (named after the `applicationName` property) that contains all the subfolders and files contained in the build/install/myApp folder when running `installApp`.

For example, after running the `installApp` task a typical folder structure created in build/install is:

```
myApp
+--- my_file.properties
+--- my_script.sh
+--- bin
|    \--- run
\--- lib
     \--- some-lib.jar
```

Likewise, the generated zip or tar archive contains the myApp folder with all its subfolder.

I'd like the archive not to contain the myApp folder at all but just the files and folder contained in it, in the root of the archive.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you give an example of the produced output and what you expect? What do you mean by "flattened in the root of the archive"?

Comment: Sorry I wrote that in a rush. Updating/